# How to read value from volume-mounted K8's secret file in SpringBoot application and reload property automatically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

I have a use case where I have to read credentials like user and password from secrets that are volume-mounted. I have tried to use
spring cloud starter config and actuators but it require to call */actuator/refresh* endpoint which I am trying to avoid.

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-config', version: '3.1.5'
```

*spring.config.import=configtree:*

is there any way to resolve this?
to reload the property when there is a file change.